# Get LDAP attributes from apache on react typescript with vite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, apache, vite

I'm building app with react + typescript + vite, dockerized and running on apache reverse proxy.
Now, I've added LDAP user auth on apache and set user attributes.

If I use a PHP Page with "getallheaders()" method por $_SERVER[ variable] allí works fine.

But I can't get the same result on react typescript with vite for attributes (or headers) from apache.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using fetch('/') for example you should be able to get the information as follows:

```
const headers = response.headers;    
const ldapUserAttribute = headers.get('LDAP_USER_ATTRIBUTE');
```